# How do I get parent position of a expandable ListView

Tags: android, position, expandablelistview

I have an activity with a Expandable Listview inside, my goal is to open different activities depending on two factors: which parent and child view the user clicked on.

I want to know how to get both (parent and child) position.

Here's and example of what i'm trying to do:

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    String name=((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TVC1)).getText().toString();      
    Intent h = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), History.class);
    Intent f = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Fighters.class);
    if(nombre.equals("History")){
        startActivity(h);
    }
    if(nombre.equals("Fighters")){
        if(flist.getSelectedItemPosition()==0){//code that i want
            f.putExtra("id", "alliance");
            startActivity(f);
        }
        if(flist.getSelectedItemPosition()==1){//code that i want
            f.putExtra("id", "atos");
            startActivity(f);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have what you're asking for passed as arguments.

```
int groupPosition, int childPosition
```

Comment: sorry, didn´t notice that, my fault

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67561555/6854117) related to it. Can you please see it?